# Euclidean Division and Two Square Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

In [Euler's Proof of Two Square Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Euler's_proof_by_infinite_descent) he writes in one step that :

> If $x$ is a factor of $a^2 + b^2$, then let $a = mx \pm c$ and $b = nx \pm d$ where $c$ and $d$ are atmost half of absolute value of $x$

But isn't this invalid when $a$ and $b$ are less than $x$?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: $5$ is a factor of $3^2+4^2$. Let $3 = 1 \cdot 5 - 2$ and $4 = 1 \cdot 5 - 1$.

Comment: Also, Wiki writes "$c$ and $d$ are at most half of $x$ in absolute value", which you wrongly quoted as "$c$ and $d$ are atmost half of absolute value of $x$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still valid if $a$ or $b$ less than $x$. Say $a \equiv k \pmod{x}$.

If $k \le x/2$ then $a=mx+k$.

If $k \ge x/2$ then $x-k \le x/2$ so $a=x(m+1)-(x-k)$.

So whether $a<x/2$ or not does affect the statement.

Comment: $m$ can be $1$.

Comment: ... Ah, true. :)

Comment: How does it guarantee $c \leq x/2$?

Comment: @Henry  I edited to a better explanation.